# Cannot generate new REST datasource with Strongloop

Tags: express, yeoman, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm new to Loopback, was following this page here: https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/REST+connector

```
$ npm install loopback-connector-rest --save
$ slc loopback:datasource
? Enter the data-source name: testrestDS
? Select the connector ...
> REST Services (supported by StrongLoop)
```

And then I get this error:

```
events.js:154
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

TypeError: Cannot set property 'facetName' of undefined
    at exports._extend (util.js:770:21)
    at module.exports.yeoman.generators.Base.extend.dataSource (/usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/generator-loopback/datasource/index.js:169:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/yeoman-generator/lib/base.js:430:16
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

I've tried a couple other connector types in the generator and they work (like Mongo even though I don't have that connector installed).

Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit
node v5.7.1
npm v3.6.0
slc v6.0.0
loopback v2.27.0
loopback-connector-rest v1.10.2

Comment: Did you get the error during the datasource create process or when trying to run the app? I just tested on OSX and wasn't able to recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error on my command line, but not in my Docker container based on the strongloop/node image.

In both cases strongloop v6.0.0 but on different versions of node (v0.10.25 versus v0.10.38 in the Docker container) with a different version of generator-loopback (1.16.2 versus 1.20.5 in the Docker container).

I suspect that you need to upgrade to resolve this issue.